# Can you have many adjacent windows along the perimeter of the top of a wall?

Tags: windows, framing

I'm looking to build an outdoor shed with a lean-to roof, and I'd like to have windows all along the top right beneath the roof, like this picture:

[image: Shed with]

What additional engineering considerations are required for something like this? Do special windows need to be used? I don't see any room for a header, and there doesn't look to be enough space between the windows for more than one trimmer.

Comment: The window word of the day is "clearstory"

Comment: @Ecnerwal The window word of the day is "*clerestory*"

Comment: @Moshe Katz Both appear to be valid spellings.

Comment: @statueuphemism Most dictionaries I checked as well as [200 years of books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=clerestory%2Cclearstory&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cclerestory%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bclerestory%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BClerestory%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cclearstory%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bclearstory%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BClearstory%3B%2Cc0) prefer the "ere" spelling.

Comment: @MosheKatz - That's eerie!

Comment: Did this on a deck I build about 30 years ago.  Build the wall, including posts to support the roof.  Build the roof.  Then cut glass to fit the openings and secure with wooden beads (about 3/4" square) on both sides.  You may want to "line" the opening with 1x4 or some such before installing the glass, to provide a smooth surface.

Comment: (Though, to be honest, I paid a local glass shop to do the glass cutting and install, since the pieces were odd shapes on the angled sides.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This answer is pretty much the same as Jasens, I elaborated a little bit.
Each post, at the corners and between the windows are supporting a rafter, sized properly for the roof load. Set between those rafters are purlins which make up the rest of the support for the roofing. The roofing is attached to the purlins.

So to answer you first question, as long as you follow this post and rafter example, you could have as many as you prefer as long as you have enough wall space for racking resistance.

In other words, don't make the windows too tall.[image]

I added a pic to show what is going on with the roof.

Comment: I just edited the answer a bit...

Comment: Very helpful, thanks. In your picture, are the studs leading to the rafters regular 2x4s or 4x4s? I also don't see why there's no need for a top plate.

Comment: They would be 2X4s, 3 total. The center continuous and is cut under the rafter and the other 2 go on either side or the rafter, cut long enough to go to the top of the rafter The purlin(s) will be cut between the rafters but set up against the extended studs to block off the sections between the rafters to keep birds and bugs. out. The framing at the top of the door and dividing the windows top and bottom are headers, no continuous plate. Setting a continuous top plate at the top of the door and between the windows would weaken the structure. The over hangs on the sides are misrepresented.

Comment: Continued.... The overhang needs to be made like your picture, the drawing, the way the overhang is will not hold up. No structure to hold it up unless you add knee braces underneath it. Back at your mention about the top plate or headers for that matter. No they are not needed. You need to keep some wall space somewhere to act as a diagonal to keep the building from leaning one way or the other.

Answer (score 5):

There's posts (the corner studs) between those windows that hold the roof up.

there's no special requirements for the windows.